# An inequality on variance of Banach valued random variables

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a separable Banach space with norm $\|\,\cdot \,\|$ and let 
$X$ be a $\mathscr{X}$-valued random variable defined on a probability space $(\Omega ,\mathscr{F}, P)$. The expectation $EX$ is defined to be the Bochner integral of $X$ with respect to $P$, i.e., $
EX=\int X(\omega )P(d\omega )$. The variance is defined by
$$
E\|X-\mu \|^2, 
$$
where $\mu =EX$. My question is whether the following inequality holds or not:
$$
E\|X-\mu \|^2\leqslant E\|X-a\|^2\ (\forall a\in \mathscr{X}). 
$$
If $\mathscr{X}$ is a Hilbert space, we can easily prove it by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the identity $E\langle X,a\rangle =\langle EX, a\rangle$ (here $\langle x,y\rangle $ denotes the inner product). However, I do not have any idea to prove it when $\mathscr{X}$ is a general or reflexive Banach space. Any help would be highly appreciated.